# An application of differential geometry of curves and/or surfaces?

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces, curves

I need to expose a "simple" application of the differential geometry of curves and surfaces for a project in class, but can't find any good source to search one. Can anyone help me with a topic or a suggestion to search?

Comment: You give no indication of what your background is. But here's a good challenging problem to think about: When is it the case that when you follow the steepest route up a surface you end up with the shortest path to the top? (When is the path of steepest ascent a geodesic?) Can you characterize surfaces on which this happens? (For a hint, see #28 on p. 78 of [my differential geometry text](https://math.franklin.uga.edu/sites/default/files/inline-files/ShifrinDiffGeo.pdf).)

Comment: Well, I've seen some basic concepts: curvature and torsion of curves, frennet-serret ecuations, concep of surface in IR^3, diffeomorphisms, isometries, weingarten's map, first and second fundamental forms; normal, principals, average and gaussian curvatures of a surface, geodesics and an introduction on khristoffel's symbols of a surface (we've only seen the way to calculate them) @Ted

Comment: Take a look at my text. There are a number of exercises in there you might turn into a project, along with the one I mentioned. If you have an interest in computation, look at #16 on pp. 43-44 or #19 on p. 66. Or look at the Mercator projection, #15 on p. 43. I am fond of #16 and #17 on pp. 65-66.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may search for

- Vertical curves
- Summit curves
- Reverse curves
- Road curve
- Compound curves

For surfaces, you may see [This](http://gsl.lab.asu.edu/archive/AbelNoway.pdf)